# custom login page with spring security and JSF Pimefaces

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2, primefaces, spring-security

I want to include a custom login page with spring security and JSF Pimefaces. My custom login page is designed with Primefaces.My problem is that the login page is not displayed with primefaces components. It look like it made with html only.

this is my spring-security.xml file:

```xml
<security:http pattern="/css/**" security="none" />
<security:http pattern="/login.jsf*" security="none" />
<security:http auto-config='false'>
<security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <security:form-login login-page='/login.jsf' />
</security:http>`
```

Comment: All in all, where is your code (both attempted and working)?

Answer (score 1):

This is easy.

Name your inputs with `j_username` and `j_password` (assign ids of PrimeFaces input components) and in your action method use the request dispatcher to forward to `/j_spring_security_check`.

And ... that's it!